# Unrelated Pivot Tables slowing loops to a crawl

Tags: excel, vba

A change of scope for this project means that what was previously two workbooks must now become one workbook. Workbook has 3 sheets: Output (viewed by end users,) Data (used to drop small SQL queries onto the sheet and run logic like below,) and Data2 which has an active connection to the DB to do bigger queries on the server via pivot tables.

This code (without the Data2 sheet in the workbook) can loop through ~15k lines in less than 5 seconds

```
For i = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Not (Range("D" & i).Value > qs) And (Range("D" & i).Value < qe) Then
        Range("D" & i).EntireRow.Delete

    End If
Next i
```

Upon adding the new sheet (which has two pivot tables querying the SQL db, with several fliters, and a slicer each) this single loop (which is one of 8) takes so long to run I haven't actually let it finish. Dropping a break on the "End If" and iterating through holding F5 shows that the code is working properly. Nothing on the Data2 sheet references anything outside of the sheet. I feel like for some reason the pivot tables are refreshing through each iteration of the loop for no good reason.

Things that have not helped:

```
PivotTable("table1").ManualUpdate = True
```

or

```
application.screenupdating = false
```

or

```
application.calculation = xlmanual
```

Comment: How about `Application.EnableEvents = false`

Comment: Nope, added in and only ~300 lines had been handled after a minute.

Comment: I notice the Sheets and Range calls arent qualified with the workbook object, and may not be attached to the right excel instance - might it be possible you are setting application.calculation on the wrong excel process?  Just a wild guess

Comment: No, there is only one excel instance. One active workbook, and the loop works fine when iterating through with a break point in the VB IDE.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification which doesn't address the root problem but might speed up your processing:

```
Dim sht as Worksheet
Dim rngDel as Range

Set sht = Sheets("Data")
For i = 1 to sht.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 
    If Not (sht.Range("D" & i).Value > qs) And (sht.Range("D" & i).Value < qe) Then
        If rngDel is Nothing Then
            Set rngDel = sht.Range("D" & i).EntireRow
        Else
            Set rngDel = Application.Union(rngDel, sht.Range("D" & i).EntireRow)
        End If
    End If
Next i

if Not rngDel is Nothing Then rngDel.Delete
```

@Acantud's comment is also worth addressing: unqualified `Range` objects can cause all sorts of problems where the sheet being read/modified is not the one you want.

Comment: This speeds things up a little bit, but deleting the (unrelated) pivot table and using the code in the OP is still significantly faster. Something is causing resources to be spent on the pivot table even though the "Data" sheet isn't tied to it in any way.